# Small (Business) Server - Microsoft Windows Search or Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express

Tags: search, search-server

Users would like to able to quickly search shared folders etc. on the server.

What are the PRO's and CON's of these two technologies?

Comment: I'd like to add for anyone considering this product on SBS 2008 don't do it (or at least not without much testing).  It doesn't play well the config of IIS/Sharepoint/WSUS and can quite easily destroy your config/install.  Beware!  Hopefully Search Server Express 2010 will be kinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have looked at Search Server Express in our org, and have found that it works well for a free product, but it has pros and cons.

**Pros**

- It's free, can't beat the price
- It does what it says it will do, indexes storage and enables people to search

**Cons**

- It is IE bound... you have to use Internet Explorer to get search results
- It is kind of hardware intensive... you can't run it on just any box lying around

Thats pretty much where we left it, e are continuing to look at express as an option for the future.  There are some other options, but they cost.  The [Google Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) is kind of spendy, but a good option.  There is also an option from [Copernic](http://www.copernic.com/) that seems good also, but it costs.

Comment: I haven't heard of a search server that isn't hardware intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Your likely to add WSS or sharepoint (if it's not already in the works) the big plus for Search server is that it supports sharepoint.  Windows search would also require you to add any 3rd aprty filters (pdf etc) to each desktop but search server allows you to have a central filter repository.

Comment: Please don't assume that everyone wants to use Sharepoint!  There are a world of alternatives.

Comment: Agreed... I rather like alfresco

Comment: @crb I'd reccomend that anyone implement something that comes in the box before installing any 3rd party stuff on what's usually the only production box in the company.  I'll take the free working software over the hopefully works every day of the week.  And when talking about search you need to have software that (oddly enough) knows how to crawl the repositories metadata.