# Small Business Server 2008 - Microsoft Windows Search or Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, search-server

See Also - [Small (Business) Server - Microsoft Windows Search or Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express](https://serverfault.com/questions/40623/small-business-server-microsoft-windows-search-or-microsoft-search-server-2008)

Can anyone tell me if they have Search Server Express 2010 Beta working on Small Business Server 2010, or indeed if it is supported.  The only reference I can find is here, but given how scant it is I'm not sure I should trust it:-

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/12cf9846-b940-4441-9fc1-30016ea87e5c

Answer (score 0):

If a Moderator on their own site says it does, i'd say you are safe to think it does, even if information on it is scarce as the moment. ;)

HTH